# Unable to Build Google Test with MinGW and MSYS - crtdbg.h not found

Tags: c++, mingw, googletest, msys

I'm trying to build Google Test with MSYS and MinGW with the help of [this page](https://github.com/iat-cener/tonatiuh/wiki/Installing-Google-Test-For-Windows).

I have MinGW and MSYS installed on MS Windows 10 Home. So far I've run these commands in the MSYS terminal, in the Google Test source code directory:

```sh
mkdir build

cd build

cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..

make
```

The `make` command fails with this output:

```
In file included from c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/mkkek/googletest-release-1.10.0/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:41:
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/mkkek/googletest-release-1.10.0/googletest/src/gtest.cc:86:11: fatal error: crtdbg.h: No such file or directory
   86 | # include <crtdbg.h>  // NOLINT
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`crtdbg.h` seems to be a Visual C++ header file. I do have the Windows 10 SDK and Visual C++ installed, but the build system isn't finding the headers.

I've read [this thread](https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2418), but none of the tips there have helped.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm using MSYS2 (and MinGW/GCC that it provides), and the file is there. I suggest switching to MSYS2 (which is superior anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I switched to MSYS2 as was suggested in the comments, and I managed to successfully build the library.

I followed the directions that are on the [project home page](https://www.msys2.org/) to install MSYS2.

Answer (score 0):

With MSYS2, the [mingw-w64-x86_64-gtest](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtest) package can be directly installed in order to use Google Test.

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtest
```